Upgrade Windows Xamarin.Forms to Maui, and keep same application directory
I have a Xamarin.Forms application that produces a Windows UWP application. I have recently created a new Maui project which is, in effect, an upgrade of my Xamarin.Forms app. When I deploy the new Maui app, it needs to use the same deployment settings of the Xamarin.Forms app so it treats it like an update.
When the Xamarin.Forms app is deployed, it stores it's data in c:\users\username\AppData\Local\Packages{ApplicationId}_{AndSomeRandomChars}
In the Maui project, I have set the ApplicationId to be the same as Xamarin.Forms app, but the seemingly random characters {AndSomeRandomChars} in the folder name are not the same as the Xamarin version, and I cannot see where these originate from, or how to change them!
Any suggestions would be gratefully appreciated! Thanks!

{AndSomeRandomChars} in the folder name are not the same as the Xamarin version...you verified this after publishing you .net maui app?
